# MySQL get multiple items from a table as a input for a single field of another table

Tags: python, mysql

I have two tables one is teachers another is subjects and I need to link the subjects to the teachers , thats an easy one but the problem is that a single teacher can have multiple subjects.Thus I need a kind of array for that, so that when I do my queries with python it returns an array or should I say a 'tuple of tuple of tuples'. So can someone help me to solve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database Architecture is most important thing to decide. Here seems 2 approach one is decided by you or other to make a mapping table.

For your Approach:-

```
id teacher_name Subject
1  XYZ          1,5,6,7
```

Query:-

```
SELECT teacher_name, subject_name 
  FROM subject s 
  INNER JOIN teacher t on FIND_IN_SET(s.id,t.subject)
```

Other is make a mapping table:-

```
teacher_id subject_id
1          1
1          5
1          7
```

Query:-

```
SELECT teacher_name, subject_name 
   FROM mapping m 
   INNER JOIN subject s on m.subject_id = s.id
   INNER JOIN teacher t on m.teacher_id = t.id
```

Comment: But that entry under Subject column , will that be an int or I have to convert it into an int?

Comment: In first option entry under subject is comma separated string. You do need to worry. FIND_IN_SET automatically handles handles it. It works like FIND_IN_SET(5, '1,2,5,6,7') it returns 1 and  FIND_IN_SET(9, '1,2,5,6,7')  return false. So condition results in will be returned. Query return like [(TeacherXYZ, Math), (TeacherXYZ, Physics), (TeacherXYZ, computer), (TeacherABC, Math), (TeacherABC, Physics)]

Comment: Thanks thats what I needed to know and upto this point i was doing the separation and comparison of subject ID and Teaher ID in python.